# How to delete entire rows in Excel if column A contain text from external txt file

Tags: excel, powershell, row, vba

Hello  please help if you can.I have a text file called del.txt containing

```
STRING1   
STRING5
```

Also I have an excel sheet with almost `1 000 000` rows in it.
I'm looking for an EFFECTIVE way how to delete entire rows if text string in column A exactly matches one of text strings from `del.txt` file?

Text strings in excel file in a column A:

```
STRING1  entire row will be deleted   
STRING1  entire row will be deleted      
STRING3   
STRING3   
STRING5  entire row will be deleted
```

So in this case row with STRING1 and STRING5 will be deleted.Thank you for any suggestions.

So far I have this code below, but I don't know how to take values from external text file...

```
Sub Del_Strings()
Dim i As Long, strArr
strArr = Array("STRING1", "STRING2")
For i = LBound(strArr) To UBound(strArr)
    With [A1:A1000000]
        .Replace strArr(i), "", xlWhole
    End With
Next i
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).SpecialCells(4).EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Please provide your code and what doesn't work in it.  This site is meant to help users with their programming, not to do their work.

Comment: Formatted text items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
Option Explicit

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = Not IsError(Application.Match(stringToBeFound, arr, 0))
End Function

Sub Del_Strings()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long

    Open "C:\test\test\del.txt" For Binary As #1    '--->change file path as required
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsInArray(Cells(i, 1).Value, strData) Then 
            Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Ask me if you have any queries.